# Android SDK Manager failed to parse xml

Tags: android, xml, sdk, android-sdk-manager

after several month when i tried to open Android SDK manager i realized it's not loading any of packages that i didn't install or have updates and just showing already installed packages (like there is not any internet connection), but there isn't any connection error shows in log like image bellow

[image: log]

i checked Official Add-on site list and it's Empty

[image: add-on site]

i checked sdkmanager.bat file in tools\bin path and i got this error that can't parse xml file

[image: xml]

note that i can access the xml file manually when enter it's path in browser.
is there anything i can do to fix this?

**UPDATE**

I figured out the reason of this problem and i added an answer for it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well the issue is that android sdk manager never checks if the downloaded page from request for getting xml files are correct or not so it couldn't detect my proxy automatically and gets some failed pages instead of correct xml files and parsing them results those errors. adding Http proxy and port in options simply resolve this issue. i hope android sdk checks the connection better so me and maybe others time will not waste in such these issues.

Answer (score 1):

The standalone SDK Manager has been deprecated and the repository urls have changed. The updates are now available from within Android Studio so you need to update it.

Comment: so what if i don't want to install android studio and just have android SDKs?

Comment: @MasihAkbari Get the command line tools from the Android Studio site. They will allow you to install the SDK using the `sdkmanager`.